# Unable to load Image after creating it with kivy android

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

- kivy 2.2.1.
- kivymd 1.2.0.dev0
- python3
- opencv-python 4.8.0.76 (camera provider)

I'm trying to take a picture with my phone/desktop camera, and retrieve it in a SmartTile, working on desktop but not in android. I got an error : Logs tells me that  the image is Not found.
When clicking at the camera icon, it launches the camera provider, and let you take a picture then click on close 'X' icon to switch from screen B to A. AS you can see, the image is not loaded. Logs tells me that the image is correctly saved, but not found. Here is the code :

```
import os
from kivymd.uix.imagelist import MDSmartTile
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera, CoreCamera
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.logger import Logger

def log(msg):
    Logger.info(msg)
    
KV = '''

<MyMDSmartTile>:
    radius: 24
    box_radius: 0, 0, 24, 24
    box_color: 0, 0, 0, .5
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: "160dp" # à faire varier
    mipmap: True

    MDIconButton:
        icon: "camera"
        on_release: 
            app.root.tile = root
            app.root.ids.camera.play = True
            app.root.title = root.text
            app.root.current = "picture_screen"

    MDLabel:
        text: root.text
        bold: True
        font_style: "Caption"
        opposite_colors: True


MyMDScreenManager:
    cam: camera
    MDScreen:
        name: "home_screen"
        MDScrollView:
            do_scroll_x:False
            do_scroll_y:True
        
            MDGridLayout:
                id:mybox
                cols: 2
                adaptive_height: True
                padding:10
                spacing:10
 
    MDScreen:
        name: "picture_screen"
        MDFloatLayout:
            Camera: # you need opencv module
                id: camera
                # resolution:(640,480) # if not specified, best resolution
                play: False

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "camera"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            on_release: 
                root.captureyouface(root.title)

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "close"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .8, "center_y": .5}
            on_release: 
                root.close()
'''
class MyMDSmartTile(MDSmartTile):
    text = StringProperty()

class MyMDScreenManager(MDScreenManager):
    
    cam = ObjectProperty()
    title = StringProperty()
    tile = ObjectProperty()
    source = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):

        #Create the tiles
        for i in range(10):
            self.ids.mybox.add_widget(MyMDSmartTile(text = str(i)))

    def captureyouface(self, txt):

        # AND EXPORT YOU CAMERA CAPTURE TO PNG IMAGE
        # GET SELECTOR FROM KV FILE CAMERA 
        if platform == "android":
            from android.storage import app_storage_path, primary_external_storage_path
            path = os.path.join(app_storage_path(), 'images', txt  + '.png')
        else:
            path = "./images/{}.png".format(txt)
        log("saving image here ------------------------------> path is : " + path)

        self.myimage = Image()
        self.cam.export_to_png(path) #export_as_image().save(path) same
        self.myimage.source = path
        self.source = path
        self.tile.source = self.source

    def close(self):
        self.current = "home_screen"


class CameraCuisto(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self, **kwargs):
        if platform == "android":
            from android.storage import app_storage_path, primary_external_storage_path
            from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
            request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.CAMERA])
            log('Perm requested')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CameraCuisto().run()
```

and here is my buildozer.spec file

```
# (str) Title of your application

title = CameraCuisto

# (str) Package name

package.name = cameracuisto

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)

package.domain = org.test

source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)

source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,txt,csv,json,atlas

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)

source.exclude_exts = spec

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)

version = 1.0

requirements=python3, kivy==2.2.1, https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip, PySDL2, pillow, opencv-python

orientation = portrait

# change the major version of python used by the app

osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use

osx.kivy_version = 2.2.1

fullscreen = 0

# (list) Permissions 

android.permissions = INTERNET, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA

android.api = 29

android.minapi = 21

android.sdk = 28

[buildozer]

log_level = 2

warn_on_root = 1
```

Comment: that spec file is 557 lines, of which 20 aren't comments/whitespace. do you think this question contains a decent [mre]?

Comment: Sorry for that, my mistake, it's updated. Thanks Christoph

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a workaround that took me a while.. For me the export_to_png was the origin of the issue so I looked for another way : here is the snippet code that worked for me on android 10 API 29 :

```
def captureyourface(self, txt):
    # print("captured")
    self.text = txt
    self.path = os.path.join("images", self.text  + '.png') #saving to folder image in root project
    camera = self.ids["camera"]

    # capturing the pixels of the camera area, in bytes format
    pixels_data = camera.texture.get_region(x=camera.x, y=camera.y, width=camera.resolution[0], height=camera.resolution[1]).pixels
    # Creates a copy of an image memory from pixel data in a buffer
    image = PIL.Image.frombytes(mode="RGBA", size = (int(camera.resolution[0]), int(camera.resolution[1])), data = pixels_data)
    # rotate image, you'll see that android add some unwanted rotation
    image.rotate(90)
    # save the image (needs storage permission in buildozer.spec)
    image.save(self.path)
    # the image can take some time, we can schedule it :
    Clock.schedule_once(self.load_image, 1)

def load_image(self, dt):
    self.source = self.path
    self.tile.ids.image.reload() # need reloads to be able to capture another one
    self.tile.source = self.source
    self.tile.ids.image.reload()
```